# Generics typecasting in case of List

Tags: java, generics, casting

Why doesnt the following code get compiled? I know changing it to String works but why we are unable to typecast from string to object?

```
List<Object> c4 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using generics, the inheritance concept is little bit different. You need to use [wildcards and sub typing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) to achieve inheritance with generics.

As per [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

> Note: Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and
>   Integer), `MyClass<A>` has no relationship to `MyClass<B>`, regardless of
>   whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of `MyClass<A>`
>   and `MyClass<B>` is Object.

Comment: That link is so helpful

Comment: List<? extends Object> c4 = new ArrayList<String>()  may cause errors at runtime?

Comment: No it will not. Again as I said in my comment you cannot add anything to the List in this case.

Comment: Generics are compile time type safety stuff. After compilation generics will be replaced with corresponding nearest objects (type erasure) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.

Answer (score 1):

Although `String` is a subclass of `Object`, `List<String>` is *not* a subclass of `List<Object>`.

The reason is that if it were a subclass, it would allow the following:

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> listB = listA; // normally a compile error
listB.add(new Integer(1)); // it would allow this
String s = listA.get(0); // boom! ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this worked

```
List<Object> c4 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

you could then go add

```
c4.add(new YourCrazyObjectThatIsNotAString());
```

which doesn't make sense because `c4` should really be an `ArrayList` of `String`s.

Generics were invented in part so that this wouldn't happen. [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20650158/438154) and [Nambari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20650169/438154) have the technical reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object> c4 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now you can add anything that is Object which is technically every Object. Which is incorrect because List is really of String. Hence it is not allowed.

So lets say you add some custom Object to the list. Then while fetching the object it will try to typecast to String which will throw incorrect cast exception. To avoid this ambiguity java does not allow it.

In general

```
List<SomeObject> l = new ArrayList<SubClassOfSomeObjectClass>;
```

is not allowed. However you can do something like

```
List<? extends SomeObject> l = new ArrayList<SubClassOfSomeObject>;
```

Comment: In this case List<? extends Object> c4 = new ArrayList<String>(); also there is a possibility of exception right ?

Comment: Nope! This will compile and run just fine. Only drawback of this is you cannot add anything to the List(except null of-course).

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> lo = ls;
lo.add(new Integer(5));
String x = ls.get(0);
```

Generics are invented to prevent some of class-cast exceptions. But if it was possible to assign `List<String>` to an `List<Object>` then you could do everything to break their power.